# Regex - Unable to capture boundaries

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I am having challenges capturing the dynamic value using regular expression in JMeter.

Tried the below Regex but it did not work. Have no idea how to handle | |

```
RegEx: dataItem|sm|(.+?)==
```

**Response Code:**

```
|ManageCards|136|dataItem|sm|JEGTzZZa9Wt4I4VMJXZ3Wb/DBPXFfXXp4keKKiDkZRx4UoLweXzodJsKG3G+gq73MLlydBc8gPZLggmsscrorEBtZL3dD1e1+3GHHga2uJ/5Y5JakcPjgsuwx1591nmyY7EjCg==|83|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentWithTags|{"text":" var API_KEY = \u0027MX84-CC53-JJ99-FU96\u0027;","type":"text/javascript"}|
```

**Dynamic Value to Capture:**

```
JEGTzZZa9Wt4I4VMJXZ3Wb/DBPXFfXXp4keKKiDkZRx4UoLweXzodJsKG3G+gq73MLlydBc8gPZLggmsscrorEBtZL3dD1e1+3GHHga2uJ/5Y5JakcPjgsuwx1591nmyY7EjCg==
```

Comment: Try this Regex

(J[^]*==)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below RegEx:-

[image]
[image]

You can also make it from |sm| also. Just use \ before the pipe symbol.

Hope this helps.